# python *args as an tuple? directory?

Tags: django, python-3.x, function, arguments

How can I turn a phrasebook into a 
*argument

I mean, specifically, the example in django

we have:

`.order_by('field1', 'field2'...)`

and I'd like to do

```
if sort =="byName":
                  a=[] #????
                  a.append('name')
                  a.append('surname')
                 .order_by(a)  #???
```

Comment: Yes? Just use `order_by(*a)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if sort =="byName":
                  a=[] # YES it can be table
                  a.append('name')
                  a.append('surname')
                 .order_by(*a)  # !!!! *a !!!
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.